# Group bar plot in percentage for each row in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

In this dataframe `Liked_by` and `Disliked_by` has been converted in percentage. I have tried several ways like `ggplot2` for gaining an output like this example: [image]

In my case the tag lines will be `name 1, ... , name 5`, and the bar plots will be `support` and `oppose` in **percentage**. The dataframe is below:

```
    df <- data.frame(Liked_by = c(0,0,1,9,2), Disliked_by = c(1,0,0,7,3), Recipient_Number = c(4,5,9,2,3), Name_Users = c("name 1", "name 2", "name 3", "name 4", "name 5" ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

df$Recipient_Number <- df$Recipient_Number + 1 

df$support <- round((df$Liked_by/df$Recipient_Number)*100) # Liked_by rounded up
    # with percentage to call support 

df$oppose <- round((df$Disliked_by/df$Recipient_Number)*100)

# users <- c("Support", "Oppose")
# df1 <- data.matrix(df[ ,5:6])
# barplot(df1, main="Support vs Oppose", ylab = "in percentage [%]", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.4, beside=TRUE, col=rainbow(10))
# barplot(df1,main = "Overall support-oppose", names.arg = users, xlab = "users", ylab = "support vs oppose", col = rainbow(20))
```

Comment: It's not wholly clear what you're going for, but for some ggplot code faintly equivalent to your barplots, try `ggplot(tidyr::gather(df, var, value, support, oppose), aes(x = Name_Users, y = value, fill = var)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')`. Note you need to melt your data to long format so you can color by support/oppose, here using `tidyr`.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it is giving output side by side, can I do it one on another, and also mark the numbers in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rearrange your data so it suits your plotting needs. In this case, you need `support` and `oppose` to be melted into one column so you can group the bar fills by them. If you want to add labels, you'll also need to figure out how high to plot them, which takes a little thought.

Ultimately, you can either plot with the default bar position, which is `"stack"` for `geom_bar`, or change it to `"fill"`, which scales everything from bottom to top like the example you posted above. The code is similar:

---

### `position = "stack"`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

              # melt support and oppose columns together
df2 <- df %>% gather(var, value, support, oppose) %>% 
    group_by(Name_Users) %>% 
    # add label_height column at half of support and support + half of oppose
    mutate(label_height = ifelse(var == 'support', 
                                 value / 2, 
                                 sum(value) - value / 2))


ggplot(df2, aes(x = Name_Users, y = value, fill = var)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +    # plot bars to height of value column
    geom_text(aes(y = label_height, label = paste0(value, '%')))    # add labels
```

[image: stacked barplot]

---

### `position = "fill"`

```
              # melt support and oppose columns together
df3 <- df %>% gather(var, value, support, oppose) %>% 
    group_by(Name_Users) %>% 
    # add label_height column like before, but scaled by dividing by the sum of each group
    mutate(label_height = ifelse(var == 'support', 
                                 value / 2, 
                                 sum(value) - value / 2) / sum(value))

ggplot(df3, aes(x = Name_Users, y = value, fill = var)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill') +    # scale bars from 0-1
    geom_text(aes(y = label_height, label = paste0(value, '%')))    # add labels
```

[image: filled barplot]

---

Obviously neither plot is production-ready and both could use some polishing, but the core functionality you need is here.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you so much. it is working nicely. :)